# The equation $175a + 11ab + bc = abc$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider all the triples $(a, b, c)$ of prime numbers that satisfy the equation
$$175a + 11ab + bc = abc\ .$$
Compute the sum of all possible values of $c$ in such triples.

I could only get to the point where $a$ is equal to $b$ or $c$; $b$ is equal to $5$ or $7$ or $a$; $c > 11$. Сan you please help me with further solution?

Comment: If $a=b,$ then $175+11a+c=ac$ or $(a-1)(c-11)=186=2\cdot 3\cdot 31.$ If $a=c$ then $175+12b=ab$ or $(a-12)b=175.$

Comment: Can you show how you got to that point? I didn't reach case 3 of $c > 11$.

Comment: I found the following solution based on your input: (a,b,c)=(7,7,42) algebraically by first using $b=5$ which fails, then $b=7$ that leads to $c=42$ and the leads to $a=7$. If this could help I could explain. I don't know how to get other values of $c$.

Comment: Apparently very few triples with $a,b$  prime and $c$ an integer. When $c$  is also prime, I get just these three:  $(2,2,197); (37,7,37); (47,5,47).$   Suggesting, with all three prime, either $a=b$  or $a=c$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solutions are $(47,5,47),(37,7,37)$ and $(2,2,197)$ hence the required sum is $47+37+197 = 281$.

Given $175a + 11ab + bc = abc$, LHS is divisible by $a$ iff $a|bc$ and since $a,b,c$ are primes, we must have $a = b$ or $a = c$.

**Case 1**: If $a = b$ the
$$
175a + 11a^2 + ac = a^2 c
$$

$$
c(a-1) = 175 + 11a = 186 + 11(a-1)
$$
Hence $(a-1)|186$ or $a-1$ is one of the divisors of $186$ or $a-1 \in (1,2,3,6,31,62,93,186)$ or $a \in (2,3,4,7,32,63,94,187)$. Out of these, the only possible prime value of $a$ are $(2,3,7)$.

If $a = 2$ then $c = 197$ which is a prime. If $a = 3$ then $c = 104$ which is composite. If $a = 7$ then $c = 42$ which is composite. Hence the only solution in this case is $(a,b,c) = (2,2,197)$

**Case 2**: if $a=c$ then
$$175a + 11ab + ab = a^2 b$$

$$
b(a - 12) = 175 = 5^2 7 \tag 1
$$

Since $b$ is prime, the possible values of $b$ are $5$ or $7$. If $b = 5$ then $a = 47$ which is prime and if $b = 7$, then $a = 37$ which is also prime. Hence the solutions in this case are $(47,5,47)$ and $(37,7,37)$

Answer (score 2):

You already have $a=b$ or $a=c$ and there is the justification for it already above. Let's make two exclusive classes with $a=b$ (and may or may not equal $c$ as well) or $a=c \neq b$.

$$
175a+11ab+bc=abc\\
175a=(ac-c-11a)b
$$

This is the $b = 5,7,a$. That is the second condition you had established that you knew in the question, but I'm including it for completeness.

So now we have 3 mutually exclusive cases

- $a=b$
- $a=c \neq b=5$
- $a=c \neq b=7$

Third case:

$$
175a+77a+7a=7a^2\\
(175+77+7)a=7a^2\\
259=7a\\
a=37\\
(a,b,c) = (37,7,37)\\
$$

Second case:

$$
175a+55a+5a=5a^2\\
(175+55+5)a=5a^2\\
235=5a\\
a=47\\
(a,b,c) = (47,5,47)\\
$$

First case:

$$
175a+11a^2+ac=a^2c\\
175+11a+c=ac\\
175=ac-11a-c\\
175=(a-1)(c-11)-11\\
186=(a-1)(c-11)\\
2*3*31=(a-1)(c-11)\\
$$

$a$ must be such that $a-1$ is a factor of $186$ so for choosing that factor to be $1,2,3,6,62,93,186$ respectively we get $a=2,3,4,7,63,94,187$ of which $2,3,7$ are kept because $a$ must be prime. In those cases $c=197,104,42$. The demand on $c$ being prime too means only $(2,2,197)$ remains from this case.

$$
c_{sum} = 37+47+197
$$